# Send request and receive response from Server in firefox extension using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, firefox-addon, xmlhttprequest

I am building a Firefox addon. I am trying to send a request to server and then get response accordingly using AJAX. The code I am using is:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: myurl
}).done(function( data ) {
   alert( data )                    
});
```

But I am not able to get the response. My request is reaching the server but I am not getting the response. I am rendering my data as JSON on the server.

I have tried different methods like simple ajax call, `XMLHttpRequest` etc. but no  luck. This code is already working in my Chrome extension. Is there something I am missing? Are there any security issues with Firefox? Or what is the best way in Firefox to make a server call and get back the response?

Comment: If you put in an error, what does it say:error: function (jqXHR, status, error) { alert(jqXHR + ": " + status + " :" + error); }

Comment: Mark: After the call It always lands up in error method.

Comment: You need to check the error message you get in your error method. I also have a firefox plugin which sends ajax requests to foreign web pages and this works fine. So it is not related to firefox security.

Comment: eX0du5: I was concerned coz the same code works fine with chrome extension. But when I try to use this in firefox it fails. BTW, how do you send back response from the server.

Comment: IF this is a .net server, look for the .d object on the return data.  Also, in IE (I know this is firefox) if you do not send data, you must often send data:"{}", for it to work correctly.  Without the actual error posted, hard to go further.

Comment: You can use XMLHttpRequest. see this post:
[here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231346/how-to-create-a-json-post-request-in-firefox-extension